# Split a document into several files: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: books, organisation

I'm wanting to split a document into several files as follows and as shows the attached picture:

> main file main.tex is in principal folder.

In each chapter file I input 2 files namely `header.tex` and `structure.tex`

So for example, in `chap1_langFormels.tex` file, I have the following file organization:

```
\input{../header}

\chapter{Introduction}
                    
    text

\chapter{Languages}

    text

\end{document}
```

Here is `header.tex` source code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\input{../structure}
%\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm, paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

%\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedLeft}X}

\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}X} % new

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathsf{OT1}{lcmss}{m}{n}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}    %% Unité

\hypersetup{pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}} % Uncomment and fill out to include PDF metadata for the author and title of the book

\begin{document}

\newpage
~\vfill

\chapterimage{1.pdf} % Table of contents heading image

\pagestyle{empty} % Disable headers and footers for the following pages

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right side of the book

\pagestyle{fancy} % Enable headers and footers again
```

`Structure.tex` file code is [here](https://pastecode.io/s/zhevwmbv).

I'm having the following error message:

```
pdflatex chap1_langFormels.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./chap1_langFormels.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                              
l.16 \usepackage
            {multicol}
?
```

The entire `chap1_langFormels.log` file content is [here](https://pastecode.io/s/83xn8797).

Same problem happens for `/principal/main.tex` file. Thank you for any help.

**Edit**

I have just tried the following: in `chap1_langFormels.tex file` when I comment the line inputing `structure.tex`, there is no longer error. The compilation goes fine. When I uncomment this same line `structure.tex` in `chap1_langFormels.tex file`, I get the same error message `Missing \begin{document}`and showing the same `\usepackage{multicol}` line as previous. After that I copied the content of `header.tex` and `structure.tex` directly into `chap1_langFormels.tex` to have only one file. After compilation, I got the same error message `Missing \begin{document}` and showing the same `\usepackage{multicol}` line as previous. So it look like if this line `\usepackage{multicol}` in `header.tex` is in conflict with something in `structure.tex`.

[image: Folder organization]

Comment: the log you show does not match the input you show, it shows `chap1_langFormels.tex` being onput and then (without any more files being input) `\usepackage` being seen on line 16.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have edited the question to add the full log output.

Comment: I don't in general follow external links, I did that time but that is still a truncated file and does not show the error at all, try to cut down your example remove all packages not needed to show the problem, then show the log (or at least theterminal outout) in teh question, the  log currently showing in the question is not helping anyone answer.

Comment: \usepackage {multicol} being seen on line 16 is line 16 of header.tex file

Comment: sorry we try to help but we need some clues. multicol is not on line 16 of the file shown here, the log file shown here does not show header.tex being included and the log file at the external link shows header.tex being included but is incomplete and shows no error.

Comment: I understand what you think. But I have the exact organization of files as shown above in the question. I really don't know why the log file doesn't show the input of `header.tex`. In `chap1_langFormels.tex file`, I have inputed `header.tex` and in the latter have inputed `structure.tex`. I have updated the question with some other information.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your `structure.tex` and deleting lines while keeping the error produces a more reasonable test document

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}



\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics



\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The second call to `microtype` generates the error (showing whatever is on the following line, that happens to be `multicol` here) <strike>That looks like a bug in `microtype`</strike> but as you can not load a package twice, just deleting the second call would also work.

The terminal output that matches this test file is

```
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 \usepackage
                {multicol}
?
```

Actually the `microtype`package isn't at fault here that combination on a second call to the package (which should give an option clash error) gives a missing begin document error with any package. Investigating...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{indentfirst} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

%\tracingall
\usepackage[activate={}]{indentfirst}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: same [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387081/7674) (probably should have reported it back then...)

Comment: @Robert ah thanks, Joseph and I are looking, not sure if we can change the option handler here or at least document this,

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle for your assistance. Since your first answer I applied your proposition and a new error pop out. So I was trying to get rid of that error in vain. The code has evolve. I have had certain packages twice. Should I open a new discussion to post the new code of my 3 files?

Comment: @cProg feel free to ask a new question but please (as in the answers here) try to make more reasponable test files, it would not have taken you long to do as I did before posting, delete everything that you could delete while still making the error so ending up with a simple one-file test file of a few lines. You did not need three files here.